# How to find eigenvalues of real symmetric tridiagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Like this(not just 5*5,maybe n*n):
\begin{bmatrix}-3&2&0&0&0\\2&-2&1&0&0\\0&1&-2&1&0\\0&0&1&-2&2\\0&0&0&2&-3\end{bmatrix}

The only thing i know is that this matrix is real and symmetric.
Is there any way to express its eigenvalues and eigenvectors with sine and cosine function?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean you know the rule of how to get the eigenvalues but you're asking if there is a faster way?

Comment: Not exactly.I know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of Toeplitz matrix can be expressed with sine and cosine function.Now i'm researching about real symmetric tridiagonal matrix,but i don't know how to express the eigenvalues and eigenvectors with with sine and cosine function.@FareedAbiFarraj

Answer (score 2):

I will first assume that for larger than $5 \times 5$, it is the the $[1,-2,1]$ that will be extended in the middle rows.

Call the matrix $\bf A$. You can assume $\bf A = R+T$, where $\bf T$ is Toeplitz and $\bf R$ is some residual matrix. So set for example $\bf T$ the tridiagonal matrix with diagonals $[1,-2,1]$. Now the eigenvalues of $\bf R+T$ will be the eigenvalues $\bf T$ but a few times perturbed by the (extremely sparse) $\bf R$ matrix.

For Toeplitz matrices there exist very efficient ways to find eigenvalues as well as eigenvectors. You can start with your favourite one of those. Then what you need to do is to update these a few times with the information in the $\bf R$ matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I will try this method.